# UWP - SQLite issues when compiling in native

Tags: c#, sqlite, raspberry-pi, uwp, iot

I was developing my app using SQLite, on "Debug" mode, worked perfectly.

When I try to "Release" it (Compiling "Native"), the problem started, looks like UWP doesn't support Reflexion.

I'm currently using this packages:

```
SQLite.Core.UAP
SQLite.Net-PCL
```

For example, if I try to do this:

```
  private void CreateDatabase()
    {
        var dbPath = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "StoredEvents.sqlite");
        SQLiteConnection SQLiteConn = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), dbPath, false);

        SQLiteConn.CreateTable<StoredEvents>();            
    }
```

These are some of the error:

```
ILTransform_0027: Method 'CreateLambda' within 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression' could not be found. 


Error at SerializationAssemblyGenerator.Program.AddKnownContractsLists(McgCodeTypeDeclaration container, ContractTables tables) 


Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       at SerializationAssemblyGenerator.Program.GenerateDataContractSerializerHelperCode(IEnumerable`1 contracts, IEnumerable`1 jsonContracts, IEnumerable`1 wcfSerializers)  



ILTransform_0000:       MCG : warning MCG0006: Unresolved P/Invoke method '_TPM_Init!tpm.dll' in assembly 'TSS.UWP, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it is not available in UWP applications. Please either use an another API , or use [DllImport(ExactSpelling=true)
```

How should I refactor the code?

Should I use a different Library?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when i was updating my apps from Silverlight to UWP. I read an article somewhere ( Tried to find it but was unable to ) which says SQLlite for UWP is available for Windows 10 deployment.

[image]

The above is a VS Extension. You can get there from Tools ->> Extensions & Updates

Below is how my References look like.

[image]

Also I noticed that you are not closing your db connection. Always better to use it inside a `using` statement. your `CreateTables()` will look something like below.

```
private void CreateDatabase()
{
    var dbPath = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "StoredEvents.sqlite");
    using (SQLiteConnection SQLiteConn = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), dbPath, false))
    {
        SQLiteConn.CreateTable<StoredEvents>();
    }     
}
```